# AudioRecord и AudioTrack

Tags: java, android

Необходимо записать аудио файл, 3 секунды, и затем воспроизвести его в обратном порядке используя `API Android`

`mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(3000);` таким образом задаю интервал записи, но воспроизвоидит оно только после вызова метода `mediaRecorder.stop();`

`mediaRecorder.stop();` использовать перед вызовом воспроизведения?
И как воспроизвести в обратном порядке?

Comment: Посмотрите вот это решение (воспроизодить задом наперед)http://stackoverflow.com/a/1417396/4829111

Comment: А есть еще варианты